# What is the best apprach converting html string to react components?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm getting the "body" content from CMS that comes as HTML string i.e

body: `"<h1>This is the title</h1><p>This is the body</p>"`

I do not want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: body }}`

I would rather have the content as an object i.e:

```
const content = {
  h1: This is the title,
  p: this is the body,
  h1: this is another title,
  p: this is another body
}
```

Then I might be able to `Object.entries(content).map...` this to my `Text` components.

Am I heading in the right direction? what would be the alternatives?

Comment: If you can have the data as JSON instead of HTML, yes, you could map it to JSX, otherwise, you'll be forced to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.